# Android volley proguard throws java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub

Tags: android, android-volley, twilio, proguard

I'm using Android Volley network library which when kept in debugging + release modes works perfectly fine, until I added **Twilio client SDK**. Now it works fine when in debugging mode but when in release mode throws this error

```
 E/Volley: [105358] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
                                       at org.apache.a.h.<init>(SourceFile:6)
                                       at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(SourceFile:109)
                                       at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(SourceFile:97)
                                       at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(SourceFile:114)
```

The log taken from the `error` interface of the Android volley string reqiest

```
01-10 16:42:27.330 522-522/? D/LOGINACTIVITY: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!-java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!-java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
```

Have looked for the same and got some response where they are asking to keep the `JUint` in top of the dependency list. Still the error persists. Any sort of help will be appreciated. TIA

Update 1:

Codebase added

```
StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    ....

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("LOGINACTIVITY", error.getLocalizedMessage() + "-" + error.getMessage() + "-" + error.getCause());

                }
            }) {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    // Posting parameters to login url
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("email", email);
                    params.put("password", password);
                    return params;
                }

            };

            // Adding request to request queue
            strReq.setShouldCache(false);
            strReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(AppConfig.DEFAULT_RETRY_TIME, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
```

Update 2:

Use-case added

1. App starts and requests user to allow the permissions like location, sms read, ..
2. Once the user agrees to those set of permissions, the user is allowed to enter the email-id & password.
3. Email-id & password are the parameters passed via the getParam().
4. When the following is requested through volley StringRequest it ends up going to "OnErrorResponse", where the error message is "java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!"

Update 3:

Proguard rules added

```
 # Twilio Client
 -keep class com.twilio.** { *; }
 # Apache HttpClient
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-keep public class android.net.http.SslError
-keep public class android.webkit.WebViewClient

-dontwarn android.webkit.WebView
-dontwarn android.net.http.SslError
-dontwarn android.webkit.WebViewClient

-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
```

Comment: Can you please post the code, where your app is crashing

Comment: It's not crashing rather the error interface is being triggered everytime. Shall post the code

Comment: @VictorPetrovski please check the updated question

Comment: Hi, where are you currently trying to run your application? Device or emulator?

Comment: @MarcosPlacona Hi, I'm running it on a device

Comment: Ok.. and you see this error and the communication fails? Can you add more details about the error, when it happens, what your request is, etc to the question so I can try and replicate it?

Comment: @MarcosPlacona please check the updated section 2, I have tried to provide the use case. Please let me know if more details is required

Comment: Thanks.... I presume `AppConfig.URL_LOGIN` is the url for your backend server... what is that returning? Does the request even hit your server?

Comment: @MarcosPlacona It is indeed and the values it returns are the details of the user..It's working when I tried using `postman` but in this case it's not even hitting the server it seems

Comment: Please find the proguard rules in the update section 3

Comment: My next suggestion was going to be adding Twilio client to proguard, but you've already done it right. I've used Twilio with volley before with no issues. Wondering if it could be something to do with volley's version

Comment: I'm using the previous version, I guess the deprecated one `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'`

Comment: Ok, I know this doesn't solve your problem, but do you have to use volley? Could you not use something more actual like OkHttp? See how I use it here: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-send-an-sms-from-android.html. I say this because Volley is just really old

Comment: @MarcosPlacona Well the entire product is live and since it's on top volley network lib so if I are to switch to other library now, it's going to give me some headache :D

Comment: Yeah, totally get that.... Was worth asking :-)
Would you be able to switch the version of Volley you're using to the official one and see if the error goes away? `compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'`

Comment: @MarcosPlacona Thank you for your precious time, I finally got the solution. It seems like it has to do with the old http library maybe the twilio sdk is using the same, which has the stub classes. Please refer my answer for more details. Once again thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Glad you got to the bottom of it!

Comment: @MarcosPlacona Are you aware of the error code " 53000" & message "SIP error 403".. I tried checking in the directory https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/reference but couldn't find the reference

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting my solution in case if someone finds it useful someday.

### The cause of "stub!"

> This happens when using Proguard and the **com.apache.http.legacy** library in Android SDK 23.
>
> As a matter of fact, all the methods are stubbed out to throw an exception with the message “Stub!” when you call them. How cute.
>
> The real android.jar implementations live on the emulator, or your real Android device.

So changing the proguard rules solved the following, seems like twilio is using old http library or something not sure.

So, here's my current solution

```
   # Twilio Client
 -keep class com.twilio.** { *; }

-keep class org.webrtc.** { *; }
-keep class com.twilio.video.** { *; }
-keepattributes InnerClasses

-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.commons.codec.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.commons.logging.** { *; }
-keep class android.net.compatibility.** { *; }
-keep class android.net.http.** { *; }
-keep class com.android.internal.http.multipart.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.webkit.**

-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
```

Source [Link to SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32153083)